# DraftJS editor returning incorrect state - but can alter state using the RichUtils

Tags: reactjs, typescript, draftjs

I'm having an issue with draftjs.

The Editor is returning what I assume is an old version of the editor state.

When I trace the state during render,  after the button is pressed the editor state contains the flag for being bold - however after typing in the editor component, the state object returned doesn't contain these flags.

I'm at a loss, I've tried perfectly copying code from the examples in the repo.

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
  const { main, identifier } = this.props;
  const section = getSection(main, identifier);
  const editorState = section.config.editorState; // from redux store

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const s = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(editorState, 'BOLD');
          this.updateSectionEditorState(s);
        }}
      >
        GO BOLD
      </button>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onChange={this.updateSectionEditorState}
      />
    </>
  );
}


updateSectionEditorState = (e: EditorState) => {
  const { main, updateSection, identifier } = this.props;
  const section = getSection(main, identifier);
  const newSection: DropComponent = {
    ...section,
    config: {
      ...section.config,
      editorState: e,
    },
  };

  updateSection(newSection); // dispatchs action to update state
};
```

Comment: interesting, can you make a working `jsfiddle`?